# Обработка списка словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Всех приветствую, есть такой код:

```
fish_taked = ""
for item in p.fish_data['fish']:
    for k, v in item.items():
        fish_taked += f" » {k} ⚗{v[0]} ⚖{v[1]} кг.\n"

return await ctx.reply(f" » Активная наживка: {p.fish_data['active_bait'] or 'нет'}\n"
                       f" » 1. Хлеб: {p.fish_data['baits'][0]}\n"
                       f" » 2. Червяк: {p.fish_data['baits'][1]}\n"
                       f" » 3. Насекомое: {p.fish_data['baits'][2]}\n"
                       " » Пойманная рыба:\n" + fish_taked)
```

Пример хранения данных в `p.fish_data['fish']`

```
"fish": [
    {
      "Асётр": [(2, 0.36), (1, 0.32)]

    },
    {
      "Форель": [(2, 0.255), (1, 0.542)]
    }]
```

Но на данный момент, я вывожу кадую рыбу по отдельности, что занимает очень много текста, как пример ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно подсчитать чтобы на выводе получалось: Форель - 2 шт (0.797 кг), Асётр - 2 шт (0.68 кг)
То есть - подсчитать кол-во рыб с одинаковым названием и их общим весом.

Comment: @entithat скриншот это заполненый рыбами пример, я привел маленький список для наглядности

Comment: Не очень понятен ваш выход, т.е. в приведённом вами словаре нет двух щук на 2.55кг. Поправьте либо ожидаемые выходные данные, ли входные. *Не вводите в заблуждение*

Comment: И почему вы используете такую структуру? По-моему проще сделать так: {"fish": {"Щука": [(2, 0.622), ], "Форель": [(2, 0.255), (2, 0.987)] } } и уже обрабатывать как хотите, и удобнее и быстрее

Comment: @Nobody это магическая рыба семейства осетров она волшебная прост :DD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переписал в более доступном формате:

```
from functools import reduce

d = { "fish": [{ "Асётр": [(2, 0.36), (1, 0.32)]}, { "Форель": [(2, 0.255), (1, 0.542)]} ]}

for i, e in enumerate(d['fish']):
    key = [*e.keys()][0]
    value = [*e.values()][0]
    d['fish'][i] = { key: [len(value), reduce(lambda acc, v: acc + v[1], value, 0)] }

print(d)
```

Либо однострочное решение (выглядит ужасно):

```
d['fish'] = [{ [*e.keys()][0]: [len([*e.values()][0]), reduce(lambda acc, v: acc + v[1], [*e.values()][0], 0)] } for e in d['fish']]
```

Comment: @entitah, он плюсует и тип рыбы тоже, цифры 2 это редкий, цифра 1 обычный, извините что не упомянул, можете поправить пожалуйста?

Comment: [(2, 0.255), (1, 0.542)] начальные элементы 2, 1 это тип рыбы, они в вашем решении тоже прибавились к друг другу, можно чтобы этого не было?

Comment: @Cookie, обновил

Comment: спасибо о великий маг, теперь Асётр может жить спокойно